# TransactionScope won't work with DB2 provider

Tags: db2, transactionscope, drivers

I've been trying to use **TransactionScope** with a **DB2** database (using **DB2 .Net** provider v 9.0.0.2 and c# 2.0) which SHOULD be supported according to IBM.

I have tried all the advice i could find on the IBM forums (such as [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=106298)) to no avail.

I have enabled XA transactions on my XP Sp2 machine, tried also from a Win 2003 Server machine but i consistently get the infamous error:

> ```
> ERROR [58005] [IBM][DB2/NT] SQL0998N  Error occurred during
> ```
>
> transaction or heuristic processing. 
>   Reason Code = "16". Subcode =
>   "2-80004005".  SQLSTATE=58005

The windows event log says:

> ```
> The XA Transaction Manager attempted to load the XA resource
> ```
>
> manager DLL. The call to LOADLIBRARY
>   for the XA resource manager DLL
>   failed:
>   DLL=C:\APPS\IBM\DB2v95fp2\SQLLIB\BIN\DB2APP.DLL
>   File=d:\comxp_sp2\com\com1x\dtc\dtc\xatm\src\xarmconn.cpp
>   Line=2467.

Also, granted the NETWORK SERVICE user full rights to the folder and dll.

Here's the MSDTC startup message

> MS DTC started with the following
>   settings:
>
> Security Configuration (OFF = 0 and
>   ON = 1):
>         Network Administration of Transactions = 0,
>         Network Clients = 0,
>         Inbound Distributed Transactions using Native MSDTC Protocol = 0,
>         Outbound Distributed Transactions using Native MSDTC
>   Protocol = 0,
>         Transaction Internet Protocol (TIP) = 0,
>         XA Transactions = 1

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks,
Florin

Answer (score 5):

I managed to get the creaky old IBM DB2 v7 ODBC driver working in a TransactionScope. It required:

- XA transactions enabled in MSDTC properties
- A value entered under the registry key HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSDTC\XADLL with name 'DB2CLI.DLL' and value 'C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB\BIN\DB2CLI.DLL' (path to dll in 8.3 format - v9 uses DB2APP.DLL)
- A reboot
- Not closing the connection prior to the TransactionScope being disposed. It seems obvious in retrospect. :)

I'm not sure if this is relevant to your particular scenario. The [IBM documentation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/msql00998n.html) shows reason code 16, subcode 2 as "The MSDTC is unable to register the DB2 connection." There appears to be some issue with MSDTC finding the DB2 dll - perhaps check the registry key referenced above?

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue by activating MS DTC as in the image below:

1. run **dcomcnfg**;
2. Component Services > Computers > My Computer > Distributed Transaction Coordinator
3. Select Local DTC > Properties > Security Tab:

[image: MS DTC Configuration for DB2 and Informix]

Reboot your machine and try again. Make sure you have the latest IBM Drivers. I tested with 10.1 Fix Pack 1 and Informix 11.50.

Source: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bill/archive/2006/12/12/using-msdtc-between-vista-clients-and-windows-2000-servers.aspx