# Optimize this code without using distributed transaction

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there a way this code may be more optimized then it is right now without using TransactionScope ?

```
public static bool DeleteItem(int cusID)
    {
        int result = 0;

        using (OleDbConnection myConnection = new OleDbConnection(AppConfiguration.ConnectionString))
        {
            string delOrders= "DELETE FROM ORDERS WHERE cusID=?";
            string delCustomer= "DELETE FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE cusID=?";
            OleDbCommand myCommand = null;
            OleDbTransaction tran = null;

            try
            {
                myConnection.Open();
                tran=myConnection.BeginTransaction();


                using (myCommand = new OleDbCommand(delOrders, myConnection))
                {
                    myCommand.Parameters.Add("cusID", cusID);
                    myCommand.Transaction = tran;
                    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

                using (myCommand = new OleDbCommand(delCompany, myConnection))
                {
                    myCommand.Parameters.Add("cusID", cusID);
                    myCommand.Transaction = tran;
                    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                tran.Commit();
                result = 1;
            }

            catch (OleDbException ex)
            {
                tran.Rollback();
                throw ex;
            }

            finally
            {
                myConnection.Close();
            }
        }
        return (result>0);
    }
```

Comment: Why? Whats wrong with it?  Is it slow?

Comment: FWIW: [the 3-argument form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.oledbcommand%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) of the OleDbCommand ctor allows specifying the transaction. I also prefer `using`.

Comment: Thanks pst. I have just been asked to optimize this code, Can you help me with the using block on transaction ?

Comment: @Kragen, I was just asked to optimize it. I did not see much to be optimized so I thought I'd ask the experts.

Comment: Deleting rows is pretty fast operation and it's strange if it's slow. If so, maybe there is no index on tables for cusID column.

Comment: Thanks x2. Nice point, I'll have a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why would you want to avoid Transactions if the database is supposed to be consistent while deleting records? Removing transactions here would essentially have probability to bring the database to inconsistent form.

If you just want to remove it from Code, then probably you may want to try out Transactions inside a single Stored Proc. Here are some examples

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/sqlservertransactions.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188929.aspx

Comment: I don't want to remove the transaction. Its just I don't want to use TransactionScope because it is not working on DB2 for some reason. I have been asked to optimize the code already using an explicit transaction I suppose.

Comment: See if these things help you further  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/78c6f17c-c612-4aa7-82c0-34a8ad69c07c/  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403946/transactionscope-wont-work-with-db2-provider

Answer (score 1):

Just a tip -  You can use `bool result` instead of `int result` cause function returns bool anyway.